# Mixing Firebase with MongoDB - Recommendations

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm creating a simple React-Redux Blog website. So these days i was searching and searching how to do user authentication, and i couldn't find nothing helpful, there were only auth with JWT token, which for me at this moment is really hard to understand so i came to idea, which i don't know is it good or no, so i want to hear more about it.

WHY am i doing this? Because i already made more than half website, but made mistake at beginning because i did simpliest possible auth with local storage, which is really bad...

So idea is to user register with Firebase with email and password.
Then will be created a user in Mongo with unique email(which i will use as ID), and empty other data like username, about section etc, which are not required and which user enters later. So Firebase is only for user login and sign up...

After login i am checking if user is authorized with checking if *email* in state provided by redux is empty... If is some value in it then i will allow user to do some stuff around...

So i am wondering how i'm gonna deploy it on web and will it work... Any suggestion?

Comment: Firebase is a powerful NoSQL database so it seems a bit of overkill to use it for purely authentication purposes. There are other, lighter weight solutions for that task. including the built in functionality of MongoDB. You're going to have to roll some crazy code to link the two together - otherwise your MongoDB will be exposed. Why are you using Firebase?

Comment: Only because it has simple user authentication, i can simply register and simply login user with email and password... I didnt find any other easier solution for user login and signup... And i know its stupid but i have no choice, i couldnt find anywhere how to authenticate user with mongo db... I already asked before and people said that i could use JWT, but i dont know how to implement it... Thats why... @Jay